# Alternate VisualForce page for OAuth Web Server flow

Tags: visualforce, oauth, identity

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to have two different Visualforce login pages so that some external apps use one Visualforce page to authenticate users, while others use a different page. I have a need to add custom branding/messaging for users signing in from a specific external app.

In the OAuth Web Server flow documentation I don't see any parameters that can be added to the Authorize URL that would target a specific page.  As far as I can tell the hostname in the authenticate URL is the only aspect of the URL that determines what page a user is sent to for signing in.

I would like to avoid setting up an entirely new community simply to host one login page with custom branding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do can be done. You want to see the External Identity Documentation. In particular [Dynamic Branding Using Custom Login Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_dynamic_with_custom_login_page.htm) and [Extend an Endpoint with the Experience ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_dynamic_extend_endpoint_expid.htm). The latter will be the technique you'll need to use to provide the unique branding experience for each external app.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use this to present an entirely different Visualforce page for OAuth sign-in?  From the documentation it looks like I can use the value of the experienceid as a variable in the original Visualforce page, but I need to completely restructure the page, so I don't think being able to change one variable will be sufficient.

Comment: I ended up just generating both sets of markup and using that ExperienceID variable to hide/show the appropriate chunk of markup with CSS.  Not ideal but I'm not holding my breath that I can have the controller render an entirely different Visualforce page.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is covered in a bit more detail in Trailblazer Identity group: [one](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004Y4UfH) [two](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004Tgrj6)

Comment: @KevinD I'd also look at [Create a Custom Login Page from a Github Project](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_custom_login_git_project.htm) which uses this repository [SF Identity login project](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/basic-custom-login) on GitHub. It should provide a basis for a controller that will allow you to use multiple custom pages.